# vscode only shows single item in autocomplete

Tags: visual-studio-code

This behaviour started with one of the later major updates. To further test it I created a new workspace and disabled all extensions and emptied my user `settings.json`. Am i missing something or is it actually a bug ?

[image]

Comment: holy moly, it does. Thank you @MattBierner, I coudn't find it myself